# Imported a class and make it part of my game

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, class

Hello all I was hoping to get some help with inported this class to a little game AS3

allowDomains:Array is a list of the allowed domains

My Question is where an how to write this Array
and where to place it so all get compiled with Flash CS4.

class below.

```
package com.ikonicstudios.utils 
{
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.LoaderInfo;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;

    //rootLevel:MovieClip is the location of the root timeline
    //allowDomains:Array is a list of the allowed domains
    //will return true is the domain is allowed, false if the domain is not allowed
    //displayWarning dynamically adds a message across the screen

    public class SiteLock extends MovieClip
    {

        public var domain:String;
        public var rootLevel:DisplayObject;
        private var warningText:TextField = new TextField();

        public function SiteLock() 
        {
        }

        public function checkLock(rootLevel:DisplayObject, allowedDomains:Array):Boolean {
            this.rootLevel = rootLevel
            domain = rootLevel.loaderInfo.url;

            for each(var allowed in allowedDomains) {
                if (domain.indexOf(allowed)!=-1) {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }

        public function displayWarning() {  
            var sh = rootLevel.stage.stageHeight;
            var sw = rootLevel.stage.stageWidth;
            var format = new TextFormat("_sans", 14, 0x000000, true, false, false, null, null, "center");
            warningText.text = "This domain does not have permission to host this flash";
            warningText.y = sh / 2 ;
            warningText.width = sw;
            warningText.setTextFormat(format);
            warningText.selectable = false;
            rootLevel.stage.addChild(warningText);

        }

    }

}
```

The class file runs alright when using Flash CS4.. But when i try yo use it in Flex builder, I get some warning. see below. anyone know how can can remove this warning, and fix the class to works in Flex builder. ? Thanks John

> 1008: return value for function
>   'displayWarning' has no type
>   declaration. line 39  1008: variable
>   'allowed' has no type declaration.
>   line 30  1008: variable 'sh' has no
>   type declaration. line 40  1008:
>   variable 'sw' has no type declaration.
>   line 41  1008: variable 'format' has
>   no type declaration. line 42

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var siteLock:SiteLock = new SiteLock()
if(!siteLock.checkLock(this, ["mydomain1.com","mydomain2.com"]))
    siteLock.displayWarning();
```

place this in the script at frame 0.

[I like this implementation of the concept better.](http://www.ghostwire.com/blog/archives/as3-domain-locking-swfs/)

Comment: Thanks for The Fast replied.
Works like a charm...

very much appreciated.